How to print out results (with System.out.println()) retrieved from the Facebook GraphRequest request in Android
I implemented successfully the code to make a request to the Facebook GraphRequest by using the the following code:
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
  ...
}

In some documentation I found the code below to retrieve values:
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields","name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();

I want to use System.out.println() to print out name and email of the person who logged in successfully with Facebook to my Android app. How can I invoke request to print out those values? Thank you.
UPDATE 1:
I suspect I might be experiencing the same problem reported at Facebook Integration Android: onCompleted(GraphJSONObjectCallback) block not executing: onCompleted(GraphJSONObjectCallback) block not executing
See more context of my code:
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(LoginResult loginResult) {
  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(@Nullable JSONObject jsonObject, @Nullable GraphResponse graphResponse) {
      //Access the response here and retrieve the information you want and print it out
      String rawResponse = graphResponse.getRawResponse();
      System.out.println("rawResponse: "+rawResponse);
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields","name,email");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}

I was expecting the following line to print out the response to the request, but I do not see anything printed out:
System.out.println("rawResponse: "+rawResponse);


Why would you want to invoke request when you specifically get the response in the GraphJSONObjectCallback?

@gtxtreme See my UPDATE 1 to the question. Notice how System.out.println("rawResponse: "+rawResponse); is not printing out anything for me, which is strange.

@gtxtreme It works. It just takes forever for me to see the results. More than 2 minutes for the results from System.out.println("rawResponse: "+rawResponse); to be printed out. But I guess that is a different issue.

The GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback has a method called onCompleted that has two arguments:

A JSONObject
A GraphResponse

You can access this response from inside the callback and print the values you want from there.
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                //Access the response here and retrieve the information you want and print it out
                 String rawResponse = response. getRawResponse();
            }
        });

Reference

See my UPDATE 1 to the question. Notice how System.out.println("rawResponse: "+rawResponse); is not printing out anything for me, which is strange.

It works. It just takes forever for me to see the results. More than 2 minutes for the results from System.out.println("rawResponse: "+rawResponse); to be printed out. But I guess that is a different issue.

@JaimeMontoya - That could be due to internet connection issues. After all, there is a request being made and it may take time.
